# Fix some point $a \in M$. Prove that the function $f:M \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = d(a,x)$ is a continuous function on $M$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $M$ be a metric space with metric distance function $d(x, y)$, for $x, y \in M$. Assume that $M$ has only a countable or finite number of points, and assume that $M$ is connected.

Fix some point $a \in M$. Prove the function $f: M \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = d(a,x)$ is a continuous function on $M$.

I am having trouble with this proof. I am thinking that I should compare it to a Lipschitz function using the triangle inequality, but I am not sure if that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d(a,x)\leq d(a,y)+d(y,x)\implies f(x)-f(y)=d(a,x)-d(a,y)\leq d(y,x).$$ $$d(a,y)\leq d(a,x)+d(x,y)\implies f(y)-f(x)=d(a,y)-d(a,x)\leq d(x,y).$$ Therefore $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x,y).$ So $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous with Lipschitz constant $1.$

Whether the space is countable or connected is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, yes this is what I meant by the reverse triangle inequality, but then I wrote the wrong right-hand side.

Comment: I see you fixed it.I expected it was that kind of slip.

Comment: This makes sense. But still confused as to why d(a,x)≤d(a,y)+d(y,x)

Comment: This is the triangle inequality for any metric $d.$ Intuitively, the shortest path  from $a$ to $x$ cannot be shorter than  a path from $a$ to $y,$ and then from $y$ to $ x$.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Fix $x \in M$. You have to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x, y) < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. The reverse triangle inequality gives
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |d(x,a) - d(y,a)| \le d(x,y)
$$
so $\delta = \varepsilon$ will do.

Comment: By the reverse triangle inequality, did you mean to say $\lvert d(x,a) - d(y,a)\rvert \le d(x,y)$?

Comment: This doen' work The RHS  d(x,a)+d(y,a) can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: how do I get |d(x,a)−d(y,a)|≤d(x,y) using the triangle inequality. I know I have to add and subtract the same thing within the absolute value, which then can break the absolute value into two. And if each absolute value is less than ε/2, then when you add them together you get ε which would prove continuity. But I am not sure how to use the triangle inequality

Comment: By "the reverse triangle inequality" I mean what @user254665 said below: if d is a metric then for all $x,y,z$ you have $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(z,y)$ and rearranging gives $d(x,z) - d(z,y) \le d(x,y)$. Symmetrically, $d(z,y) - d(x,z) \le d(x,y)$ and putting these two inequalities together gives the "reverse triangle inequality" $|d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \le d(x,y)$ for all $x,y,z \in X$.